# Does compiling using the g++ compiler on putty pass my code to a linux server?

Tags: c++, stack, gnu, putty

I am in university, and we normally compile our code through the g++ using putty.
When I try to compile my code locally with Visual Studio I get a stack overflow error. However, when using putty to compile on g++ I do not.

My assumption is that Windows has a 1 MB stack and Linux has a 8 MB stack. When I use putty to compile using g++ I am passing my code to a Linux machine, and thus have additional stack space.

Can someone clear this up for me?

Comment: Yes, accessing a machine through ssh will allow you to run commands on that machine. Your code is compiled on your university's computer in that case. The actual reason for the error on one system and not on the other is probably the result of undefined behavior in your code - i.e., you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: My assumption was because in the skeleton we were given to modify (but not allowed to change) had every function with this type of parameter:
void (int image[700][700])

I assumed that the error was a result of defining large arrays on the stack (in the function header) and that's why it wouldn't compile locally on my windows, but will compile through my university's linux. Because of the difference in stack sizes.

Comment: What error does Visual Studio give you?

Comment: Arrays in funciton headers always decay to pointers, thus you have `void (int (*image)[700])` which has a size of a normal pointer. You probably create that array somewhere else.

Comment: @GregKikola, the program crashes as soon as it is run. Only through debug mode do I see:          test    dword ptr [eax],eax     ; probe page.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I do define the array in main as int image[700][700] and pass it to the function. displayImage(image);

Comment: That's what eats up all the stack space. Do `int (*image)[700] = new int[700][700]` instead and don't forget to `delete[]` it later.

Comment: Sounds like @GregKikola is on the right track. If your program crashes as soon as it's run then there is almost certainly some undefined behavior occurring. Also forgive me if I'm missing something here, but the *compiler* is giving you a stack overflow or the compiled *program* is?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat So, my assumption that it eats up my 1 MB stack space on my local Windows but not when I pass it to my university linux machine (which has 8 MB) is correct?

Comment: @MS-DDOS Not sure about that. He has a huge array in `main()`, which overflows the stack as soon as the program is started.

Comment: @MS-DDOS, I assumed this is a stack overflow problem and I looked up test    dword ptr [eax],eax     ; probe page. And google keeps mentioning stack overflow.

Comment: Yeah, 700^2 pointers would eat up almost 2 MB of stack space at least, so that would be the issue. Have to allocate that dynamically on the heap.

Comment: I would recommend to add -Wall -Werror -Wfatal-errors to the compiler options and iteratively start fixing whatever fails. It might be tedious, but it's deterministic. Edit: while i wrote my comment, 20 more popped up. Maybe this is not the solution, but it will establish a clean start for debugging runtime errors.

Comment: @IgorStoppa Also -Wextra

Comment: @RyanHallberg `-Wall -Wextra` enable various useful compiler warnings. You should use those flags. `-Werror` makes them errors and `-Wfatal-errors` makes the compiler stop at a first error. I personally wouldn't enable the last two, because 1. sometimes it's useful to see all the errors and not only the first one and 2. sometimes you want to just run the code and fix the warnings later.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that is true, assuming that one can tell apart warnings that can be ignored safely from warnings that are likely to cause runtime errors.
I preferred to play it safe.

Comment: @IgorStoppa In the end I fix all the warnings too. But `-Werror -Wfatal-errors` just slow down the development.

Comment: In addition to dynamically allocating the array, you can also declare it as `static` (or as a global variable). This places the variable in a different section of memory from the stack, so you should be able to create a large array using this method. Non-constant global/static variables are something that should probably be avoided in most situations in the "real world", but for a small program (like an assignment) it's totally fine (assuming your professor hasn't added any extra stipulations).

Comment: @Cornstalks I agree, I don't write code like this, it was no doubt a student assistant. I was just wanting to verify if this is why it compiles through my university's linux but not on my windows. I am pretty sure it is because of the stack size differences between linux and windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using putty you have an SSH connection to your linux server, and you are then compiling your code on that linux system.

at the prompt in linux if your shell is `BASH` then I believe `ulimit -a` will reveal the memory limits placed on everything including `stacksize`.  If your shell is either `csh` or `tcsh` then at the prompt type `limit` to show the values placed on limits.  you can see what type your shell is by doing `echo $SHELL`.

I use SUSE and I know these settings can be found in `/etc/security/limits.conf`.  It is here that you can adjust the default 8MB placed on `stacksize`.  Since SUSE/SLES 10.1 I have experienced the default limit of stacksize to be 8MB.  Why they set it to 8MB and what security implications it has I don't know.  For years I have been modifying `limits.conf` to set `stacksize` to `unlimited` and have never had a problem.
I do not know if this file name and location holds true for all other distributions, or if 8MB is the default stacksize limit in other distributions.

Like others have said in comments, having large array variables declared within `main()` and within other functions it what's causing the problem because those variables are placed on the stack when you execute your program.  If the linux operating system is placing a hard/soft limit of 8MB on `stacksize` then you run your program needing more than that 8MB of memory on the stack = fail.

I have run into this exact problem many times over the years running code in linux, you compile no problem then go to run it and it seems to just quit or crash without explanation - when this happens always check the hard/soft limit placed on stacksize by the operating system; a quick change of stacksize to unlimited will then verify if that was the cause if the program runs to completion.

A quick way to get around this is declare those large variables globally outside of main() in your `.c` or `.cpp` file; whether this is good programming is another matter.

There is more freedom in linux and the gcc compiler will let you compile your code to create an executable without checking or complaining of declared variables exceeding the hard/soft limit placed on stacksize.  I am not sure if there is a compiler option for gcc, g++, or gfortran to check at compile time if declared variables exceed the value of stacksize.   And you can always calculate the amount of memory your declared variables will use: if an integer is 4 bytes, if you do `int myarray[700]` then that is 2800 bytes and `int myarray[700][700]` is 1,960,000 bytes which is 1.869MB.

I don't know what the default limit of stacksize is in Microsoft Windows (you mention it might be 1MB), but with Visual Studio (which i am not that familiar with) it would not surprise me if it does check during compile time if your declared variables exceed the limit placed on stacksize by the operating system.